# Trussed strongback or hollow shell strongback?

Tags: launch, rockets, launch-site, launchpad

I noticed that rocket Lab has a hollow rectangular section strongback made of steel, while few strongbacks like that of Astra [similar size] has a trussed structure for a strongback. is there any advantage of using hollow section, because most of the strongbacks are actually truss structures?

[image: Astra 3.2]
[image: Electron - rocket lab]

Comment: Hollow section would provide better protection to the plumbing inside, but add mass. (and might be more affected by rocket blast pressure). I'd also have some concerns about sound energy being reflected back to the rocket body.  No clue as to the magnitude of the tradeoffs though, i'll leave an actual answer to the experts.

Comment: I wonder whether Astra's capability of launching from anywhere in the world, and setting up a launch complex within a week starting from nothing but a slab of concrete somehow fits into this.

Comment: Without structural diagrams, how do you know the Electron strongback uses a hollow shell? Your Astra image even gives an example of an external cladding covering an underlying truss. Here you can even see panels on the Electron strongback that might line up with the cell structure of an interior truss: https://s.yimg.com/os/creatr-uploaded-images/2020-08/ab9a98f0-eb53-11ea-9172-050464e1ea05

Comment: That's a fair point, but, this photo shared by Rocket Lab shows that it is a hollow structure. sorry, I shud've included this in the question. https://twitter.com/RocketLab/status/1116772432830812160?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1116772432830812160%7Ctwgr%5E%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.redditmedia.com%2Fmediaembed%2Fbcjbjs%3Fresponsive%3Dtrueis_nightmode%3Dfalse

Comment: @suziVenus you *sure* there's not a truss hidden in there? Okay, yes, that's a rather better picture. Looks heavy, but cheap and fast to engineer and fabricate (the two halves even look nearly if not completely identical). Note that Rocket Lab's strongback doesn't have to pack away into a shipping container with the rocket for transport, it rides a short, straight set of rails between the assembly building and the launch pad. I don't have insight into their design process, but suspect it can be summed up as "it's all they needed".

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff ya, cost and time of manufacturing might be why they chose it. Apparently having less surface area exposed to exhaust gases makes shell structures easier for maintenance, not sure on what magnitude this is helping them though.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good example of the choice between a triangulated truss and Monocoque (stressed skin) designs. Both are good and widely used.

[image]

Trusses are cheap to engineer, but expensive to fabricate. Monocoque is the other way around. Of course this is a gross over-simplification, but a good rule of thumb.

To minimize material cost, the design should have a low  safety factor (risk of failure).

To predict failure, you must first predict the mode of failure. This is easy with a truss: each member is attached at only 2 points so the member can fail only in compression or tension. There are no unexpected modes of failure. It is a clear (therefor cheap) engineering problem, so the design can have a low safety factor.

Monocoque structures fail by panel buckling which is less predictable. Engineering is dicey, especially with complex structures and low safety factors.

In the days of slide rules, engineering time was expensive. With CAD, less so. As a result, Monocoque structures become more viable.